# maximum date less than the quarter date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table days table.There is oper_day  column:

| oper_day |
| --- |
| 01.01.2021 |
| 02.01.2021 |
| 03.01.2021 |
| ********** |
| ********** |
| 31.12.2022 |

I want to output the maximum date available in a table that is less than the first date of each quarter **for example:** quarter_date: 01.10.2022  if 30.09.2022 has in a table I give 30.09.2022 else 29.09.2022 .How can I write query?

Comment: `select max(oper_day) from t where oper_day < date '2022-10-01'`?

Comment: it's not that simple.Please read better.

Comment: @MiralisherMirxomidov What's wrong with the above suggestion? What do you have as input? And what do you want as an output: a single date, a date per quarter?

Comment: From the available dates in the table, a maximum date smaller than the date at the beginning of each quarter is required.

Comment: If the table has no rows after 2022-01-01, what should be an output as of today (4th quarter of 2022)?

Comment: No it is not. I know that it will definitely exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could accomplish this by putting the dates into groups by quarter. Then finding the MAX date for that quarter.

```
SELECT   ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(td.oper_day, 'Q'), 3) next_quarter_begin
        ,MAX(td.oper_day) max_date_prev_quarter
FROM     table_days td
GROUP BY ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(td.oper_day, 'Q'), 3)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: You have made the solution far too complex. `DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY td.oper_day - TRUNC(td.oper_day, 'Q') DESC` will find the maximum `oper_day` in the group (and could be simplified to `DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER  BY oper_day DESC`, since `TRUNC(td.oper_day, 'Q')` is effectively a constant within each group) and then from those rows you find `MAX(oper_day)` which is doing exactly the same thing. You can just use `MAX(oper_day)` and ignore the `KEEP` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking how to find the last date in each quarter, if so then `GROUP BY` the data `TRUNC`ated to the start of the quarter and find the maximum date in each quarter (as it will be the latest date before the start of the next quarter).

If you want to ensure that the values are from quarters before the current quarter then you can add a `WHERE` filter to ignore values in the current quarter or later.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(oper_day, 'Q'), 'YYYY-Q') AS quarter,
       MAX(oper_day) AS last_oper_day_in_quarter
FROM   table_name
WHERE  oper_day < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q')
GROUP BY TRUNC(oper_day, 'Q')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (oper_day) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01' + LEVEL - 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2022-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 <= SYSDATE;
```

Outputs:

| QUARTER | LAST_OPER_DAY_IN_QUARTER |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-1 | 31-MAR-22 |
| 2022-2 | 30-JUN-22 |
| 2022-3 | 30-SEP-22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Psth1xR)